# Laravel - How to update data calculate by it's column

Tags: php, laravel

How to update data with calculating by it's column
I have table item

```
+---------+-------+-------+-----------+
| item_id | stock | price | name      |
+---------+-------+-------+-----------+
| 1       | 10    | 9.4   | Paper     |
+---------+-------+-------+-----------+
| 2       | 10    | 12.8  | Pencil    |
+---------+-------+-------+-----------+
| 3       | 10    | 99.9  | Note Book |
+---------+-------+-------+-----------+
```

and then I wanna update the sock by calculating stock column

```
stock - $request->qty
```

If I do manualy base query

```
update items set stock = stock - 3 where item_id = 1
```

it's working, but when I use laravel eloquent the stock become 0 (zero), I dunno why,

here is my controller

```
public function saveOrder(Request $request) {
     $item = new Item;
     $item->where('item_id', '=', $request->item_id)->update(['stock' => 'stock - '. $request->qty]);
return redirect('order');
}
```

any solution? Thanks for answer, sorry for bad english :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one:

```
$item = new Item;
$item->where('item_id', '=', $request->item_id)->decrement('stock', $request->qty);
```

Comment: This solution is better, since it'll create just one query `update items set stock = stock  - 2 where item_id = 2`. Upvote.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
$item = Item::where('item_id', '=', $request->item_id)->first();
$item->stock = (int)$item->stock - (int)$request->qty;
$item->save();
```

Alternatively you could try to use [DB::raw expression](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#raw-expressions).

Comment: These are 2 queries... He is trying to get it done without getting the stock. :|

Comment: OP said nothing about queries or getting it done without getting the stock. So, I gave him two ways to accomplish his task.

Comment: @prateekkathal: I agree with Alexey Mezenin. OP just want the solution to update the column.

Comment: @VishalParkash If something can be done in just 1 query, why do it in two?

Comment: @prateekkathal yeah correct but I was just saying that his method would work as well. I have checked your answer as well and voted it . :)
Everyone has their own style of working

Comment: @prateekkathal I agree `decrement()` solution is better when you just need to decrement number. But in some cases my solution can be better option. For example, if you need to use old or new `stock` value later in the code.

Comment: @VishalParkash Thanks for the upvote. I agree everyone have their own style, but one must always try to optimize the code.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin Yes, of course.... but since it wasn't required here........

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick for you

```
public function saveOrder(Request $request) {
    Item::where('item_id', $request->item_id)
        ->decrement('stock', $request->qty);

    return redirect('order');
}
```

Comment: @yuliantosaparudin Not really... But yeah, glad I could be of help. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    public function saveOrder(Request $request){
     $stockdetails = \DB::table('tablename')->where('itemid',$request->itemid)->first(['stock as stock']);
 //update query
    $update= \DB::table('tablename')->update(['stock'=>($stockdetails->stock)-($request->quantity)])->where(itemid',$request->itemid);
    if($update){
    //sucecss
    }else{
    //Fail

    }
```

Comment: try to refactor this code, and you may achieve the same in two lines